# horizontal flipping an entire directory with ffmpeg win7

Tags: ffmpeg, batch, script, mp4, flip

I was wondering if there is a batch processing script to horizontally flip an entire folder. I have been using "ffmpeg -i inputfile.mp4 -vf hflip -c:a outputfile.mp4" but it eats up so much time. any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use powershell to do this fairly easily. First, make a new folder in your c:\videos directory called horizontal (c:\videos\horizontal) or wherever that path is.

Open notepad and paste the following and edit the videos path and the path to ffmpeg:

```
$videos = Get-ChildItem "C:\videos" -Filter *.mp4
foreach ($video in $videos)
{
c:\path\of\ffmpeg.exe -i $video -vf hflip -c:a copy "c:\videos\horizontal\" + $video.name
}
```

Save it as a .ps1 file, then right click and run with powershell.